# How to push to array with spread operator and map?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to push new files selected by a user in a `<input name="PostFiles" ref="PostFiles" multiple type="file"/>` element along with some metadata for each file.

This is what I came up:

```
const PostFiles = this.$refs.PostFiles.files;
this.Form.Files.push(...PostFiles).map(file => {
                        return [
                            file, {
                                name: file.name,
                                size: file.size,
                                type: file.type
                            }
                        ]
                })
```

So I basically want the `this.Form.Files` array to be like this:

```
[
 [{File Object},{Metadata Object}],
 [{File Object},{Metadata Object}],
 [{File Object},{Metadata Object}]
]
```

When I use my above code, the `map()` doesn't work. I only get the `File Object` part. Can I not use `map()` in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map function return a new array, it does not change the original one. So you have to assign the returned array:

```
this.Form.Files = this.Form.Files.push(...PostFiles).map(file => {
                        return [
                            file, {
                                name: file.name,
                                size: file.size,
                                type: file.type
                            }
                        ]
                })
```

Edited:
To keep the original items:

```
const PostFiles = Array.from(this.$refs.PostFiles.files).map(file => {
                        return [
                            file, {
                                name: file.name,
                                size: file.size,
                                type: file.type
                            }
                        ]
                })
this.Form.Files.push(...PostFiles)
```

Comment: But this will overwrite all the existing items in the `this.Form.Files` array which I don't want.

Comment: Edited. You map only the new files and push the results.

Comment: It needs to be `const PostFiles = Array.from(this.$refs.PostFiles.files).map(file => {` because FileList is not actually an array. Edited your answer and marked as answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `.push` will mutate the array and return the length of the new array so that's not what you want.

Replacing `this.Form.Files.push(...PostFiles)` by `this.Form.Files.concat(PostFiles)` should work.

Comment: Thank you I tried this but it doesn't work.  I still can't get the `map` bit to work on the newly added items

Comment: Then you should do `const PostFiles = this.$refs.PostFiles.files.map...`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the Map function in javascript doesn't return the modified array, but the new length of the array. So you should break that code in two separated parts:

```
const PostFiles = this.$refs.PostFiles.files;
this.Form.Files.push(...PostFiles);

this.Form.Files.map(file => {
                    return [
                        file, {
                            name: file.name,
                            size: file.size,
                            type: file.type
                        }
                    ]
            });
```

Comment: thank you - but I only want to run the `map` on the newly added items to the array, not all of them. the reason is that there may be items in the array already that have a file object and metadata object

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.Form.Files = PostFiles.map(file => ([file, {
  name: file.name,
  size: file.size,
  type: file.type
}]));
```

I don't know why you want to do it though.

Comment: It is a multiple file uploader. So the user first selects 3 files to upload. Then the user may add another 2 files to upload while the others are uploading. Therefore I must add the new files to the existing array.

Comment: In this case, you need to add a `PostFiles.push(...)` before this assignment.